# How to update list of records with special characters into sqlite table using ormlite in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I am using ormlite for database operations in my Android app. I want to update around 1000 records at a time. But, if these records have any special characters such as ' / \ % , I am getting the following exception.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing Android statement: UPDATE `staticresource`
    SET `Content` = 'Tick next to member and add by clicking on \'Invite Selected\'
    button to create invite list.' ,`Id` = '3' WHERE `Alias` = 'tm'
```

So, how to update these records optimally. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape special character's using
`DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString();`

```
String updateString = DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString("Tick next to member and add 
by clicking on \'Invite Selected\' button to create invite list.");
```

`updateString` can be pass to `ormlite` update method.

Answer (score 0):

> How to update these records optimally.

The right thing to do is to use the `UpdateBuilder` combined with a `SelectArg` (which is a poor name).  The `SelectArg` will use the `?` SQL feature in which case your string can include special characters without issue.

```
UpdateBuilder ub = dao.updateBuilder();
updateBuilder.where().eq("Alias", "tm");
updateBuilder.updateColumnValue("Content",
    new SelectArg("... on \'Invite Selected\' button to ..."));
updateBuilder.update();
```

This will generate something like:

```
 UPDATE `staticresource` SET `Content` = ? WHERE `Alias` = 'tm'
```

And it will set the `?` value to be your string.  You don't need to worry about escaping anything.  This is also how you protect user input from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.